# Link ms access to sql server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to access my MS Access database through a SQL Server R2 instance.

Is it possible? If yes than how?

Comment: Its a nice thought, but I didn't get any idea how it work. And also don't know why everyone getting rate down to this question... Now god help to solve your problem.

Comment: Add it as a linked server? Also, what does this have to do with programming?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "link" and what your goal is. Your question is very short and it's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Pondlife I just simple want to connece ms access data threw sql server. My access Db is badly designed, I juts want to access those data threw sqlserver to get data easily by applying sql queries...

Comment: I would use my answer/hints below...and then create a view to wrap the select from (jet-database).  Note, if you go to my blog, you can get the syntax sugar for a jet database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer:

OPENDATASOURCE

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx

I have a few examples [here](http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/sql-server-data-to-a-jet-database/)

My examples are not a "direct hit", but are helpful, IMHO.

Example from MSDN article:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=C:\DataFolder\Documents\TestExcel.xls;Extended Properties=EXCEL 5.0')...[Sheet1$] ;
```

Here is a longer version.
However, you need to list your Sql Server Version (32 or x64), your O/S.
A x64 Sql Server is going to have some hiccups talking to a Jet Database.

```
/* Setup */

/*
--Run this ONCE  

sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
 GO
 RECONFIGURE;
 GO
 sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
 GO
 RECONFIGURE;
 GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
 GO
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
 GO

 RECONFIGURE;
 GO

*/




CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwJetDatabaseWrapper]

AS

/*
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=C:\work2\DotNet\MultiRDBMSSupport\DataStores\AccessDatabaseCopy\Nwind.mdb;')...[Customers] ;
*/

/* OR  */


SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Data Source=C:\work2\DotNet\MultiRDBMSSupport\DataStores\AccessDatabaseCopy\Nwind.mdb;')...[Customers] ;




GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to use a linked server.  Here is a link I found with a question almost exactly like yours and a good discussion on how to set it up.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/589ca193-3541-4c5e-965c-4c515d6b476b